# 2D raycasting in unity doesn't work

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics, raycasting

So here is the code I've been working on:

```c#
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MovePlayer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float sidewaysForce;
    public float jumpingForce;

    public Rigidbody2D playerRigidbody;
    public Transform playerTransform;

    private Vector2 forceToAdd;
    private bool onGround;

    private LayerMask mask = 8;

    private void Start()
    {
        forceToAdd = new Vector2(0, 0);
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        // Basic left/right movement

        forceToAdd.x = 0;
        forceToAdd.y = 0;

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
        {
            forceToAdd.x = -sidewaysForce;
        }
        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
        {
            forceToAdd.x = sidewaysForce;
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space) && onGround == true)
        {
            forceToAdd.y = jumpingForce;
            onGround = false;
        }

        var something = Physics2D.Raycast(playerTransform.position, Vector2.down, 200000f, mask.value);

        Debug.Log(something.collider);

        playerRigidbody.AddForce(forceToAdd, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    }
}
```

And my issue is this: No matter how far I move the player upwards, whether it be to (0,5) or (0, 2044), it will still print out "Hit ground."

I've tried both Physics and Physics2D, I've tried LayerMasking, everything, and yet it won't work. I'm a beginner to Unity btw.

**EDIT:** I printed `Physics2D.Raycast(playerTransform.position, Vector3.down, 2f).collider`and I ended up with "Player," not "Ground," any way to fix this? I tried increasing the distance to 20 and to 2000, but it yields "Player," still. Any ideas?

**EDIT #2:** I also tried LayerMasks, didn't work still.

Comment: Try saving it in a variable and printing what it interacts with

Comment: Chik3k3r, see my edit

Comment: Which layer masks? Also, have you tried with an offset for the start position(example: Physics2D.Raycast(playerTransform.position + Vector3.down, Vector3.down, 2f)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are parsing Physics2D.Raycast the wrong parameters. As you can see in the Unity docs, the function takes a Vector2 and not a Vector3.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.Raycast.html

Also for testing Raycasts in Unity, always set the distance parameter to be Mathf.Infinity until you have designed the solution completely. This will save you a headache in debugging. It is also best practice to add a comment explaining that it is a temporary distance value and that it should be changed later.

When posting your questions in the future on forums, ensure that you properly explain your questions as I really had to look through your code to find what the purpose was.

I am going to refrain from commenting about your code design as this is stack overflow and not reddit but I teach programming at university and would love to help if you are open to leaning :)